# In how many ways $MISSISSISSISSIPI$ can be arranged that no 2 $S$'s > aren't aside

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> In how many ways $MISSISSISSISSIPI$ can be arranged that no 2 $S$'s
> aren't aside

What I understood is I need them in this shape

1-MSISISISISISISPS

2-SMSPISISISISISIS

I thought of assuming $M,P=I$ then calculate them as a binary sequence of 1's and 0's
such as 101010101010, $S=1$ , $I=0$
so $C(16,8)$ then we multiply by $2!$ for M,P

But I'm not sure about this approach

Comment: Did you mean mississississississipi?

Comment: Finally not a counting problem on Mississippi

Comment: @JustDroppedIn No, why?

Comment: @Mostfashma Just kidding. It sounded funnier in my head, never mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way is to take aside all the $S’s$ and arrange the letters $M,I,I,I,I,I,I,P$, which can be done in $\frac{8!}{6!}$ ways. Now, since no two $S’s$ can be adjacent, every one of the eight $S’s$ must go in one of the $8+1=9$ spaces between the letters/ at the extreme ends. For that we have $9\choose 8$ choices, giving a total of $$\frac{8!}{6!} \times {9\choose 8} = 504$$ ways.

Comment: why divided by 6! in 8!/6!

Comment: @Mostfashma Because $6I$'s are the same!